# Javascript error with cross-origin Flask server

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

I am having issues with CORS and requests using Flask and Javascript. I have an API on domain:5000/endpoint and a front-end at domain.com

I initially had a CORS error, I installed flask-cors and this has stopped the CORS error.

When I send a request via Postman to the Python server, it returns the correct response. However, my fetch request inside the Javascript fails, when I look at the chrome console, no errors are thrown from the request, but the parsing of the response throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined` . I assume this is something to do with CORS.

How can I have the Javascript Fetch access the body of the response?

**Python**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def endpoint():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        code = myFunc(data)
        return json.dumps(code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

**Javascript**

```
fetch(addr, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: projectJson
            })
                .then(
                    response => response.json(),

                    error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
                )
                .then(
                    parsedJSON => {
                        lastJson = parsedJSON;
                        window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(parsedJSON), '*');
                    }
                )
```

Comment: Wait, `.then(r => r.json(), e => console.log(e))` is not how you work with `Promise`s. If you want to `catch` an `error`, then use a `catch` handler at the end. Plus, it doesn't sound like a `CORS` issue - it sounds like you're not handling the response properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

Javascript

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint', {
  method: 'POST', 
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({'data':'data'}),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
})
```

Python

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def endpoint():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        code = myFunc(data)
        return json.dumps(code)
```

more info [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

### note

1. > A common response format when writing an API is JSON. It’s easy to get started writing such an API with Flask. If you return a dict from a view, it will be converted to a JSON response.
2. you need handle error in `.catch`
3. axios lib maybe more powerful then fetch api